# Defining boundary points of a polygon, playing around

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, definition

I was playing around with geometry and trying to come up with a definition of boundary points of a polygon and I came up with something like this:
P is a boundary point of a polygon if and only if there exists a point A in 2D space such that for all points K in line segment AP (but excluding P), K is NOT a point of the polygon (where a polygon would be some set of points in 2D space). Does that even make sense? What do you think about this? Can you send me some resources that touch upon this topic?

-high schooler with a little bit of interest in higher maths

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what you mean (I must not be alone apparently). You lack making a distinction between the interior and the boundary of your polygon. An example : If I take the square $P(0,0), Q(0,1), R(1,1); S(0,1)$, Let $A(1/2,1/2)$ ; $P(0,0)$ belongs to the square and is such that all points of line segment $AP$ belong to the interior of the square but $P$ (which belongs to its boundary). But you look to have a problem of circular reasoning because you need to define what the boundary is before you define your necessary and sufficient condition for being... on the boundary...

Comment: FYI- there is a standard definition of the boundary of any shape (i.e., set of points): If $\scr A$ is a set of points, a point $p$ is *interior* to $\scr A$ if there is some disk (2D) or ball (3D) centered at $p$ with is entirely contained in $\scr A$. $p$ is *exterior* to $\scr A$ if there is some disk or ball centered at $p$ which does not intersect $\scr A$, and finally $p$ is a boundary point if every disk/ball about $p$ contains both points in $\scr A$ and points that are not in $\scr A$. "disk/ball" = set of all points within a given distance of $p$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I made a mistake in my post. I edited it now. I meant:  P is a boundary point of a polygon if and only if there exists a point A in 2D space such that for all points K in line segment AP (but excluding P), K is NOT a point of the polygon. I forgot the "not". Another thing: I want to define what a boundary point of a polygon is and I'm asking if that definition makes sense. I would define the boundary as the set of all and exactly those points of the polygon that satisfy the condition i gave in the definition.

Comment: The polygon would be a sum of two sets: the set of those points that satisfy the condition and the set of those that don't satisfy the condition, that would correspond to the boundary and the interior respectively. I have to say my question isn't very concrete because I just wanted to see what others think about this and I wanted to know if this is a good definition, so that's why some people may not understand what i meant in the post.